# Como incluir "espaço" em cartões

Tags: javascript, string, funções

Eu preciso incluir espaços entre o titulo da pessoa, nome e sobrenome.

```js
function cartao(titulo, nome, sobrenome) {
return titulo + nome + sobrenome
}
```

O resultado disso está sendo: Dr.MatheusPeixoto sem espaços e não consigo colocar espaços usando as aspas em branco no "return" alguém me ajuda? estou começando agora e esse é um exercício de um curso que estou fazendo, mas não acho explicações com o que ja foi falado nele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matheus,

Existem várias formas de fazer isso em javascript.

Um delas é utilizando de Template String:

```js
function cartao(titulo, nome, sobrenome) {
  return `${titulo} ${nome} ${sobrenome}`;
}

let cartaoFormatado = cartao("Dr.", "Matheus", "Peixoto");

console.log(cartaoFormatado);
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

---

Você também pode fazer da forma mais comum, concatenando as strings com o operador (+):

```js
function cartao(titulo, nome, sobrenome) {
  return titulo + " " + nome + " " + sobrenome;
}

let cartaoFormatado = cartao("Dr.", "Matheus", "Peixoto");

console.log(cartaoFormatado);
```

---

Por fim, também existe o método concat da String:

```js
function cartao(titulo, nome, sobrenome) {
  return titulo.concat(" ", nome, " ", sobrenome);
}

let cartaoFormatado = cartao("Dr.", "Matheus", "Peixoto");

console.log(cartaoFormatado);
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

Comment: Daniel, obrigado por responder. Olhando suas soluções, eu reparei no que eu estava errando, estou usando o método mais comum e o que estava esquecendo era justamente o espaço entre as aspas. Aliás obrigado por me ensinar outros métodos.